# Is there a way to position a html element absolute but still place it in the center of the page?

Tags: html, css, debugging

```css
 .container{
   position: absolute;
   margin: 0 auto;// this doesn't position it in the centre anymore.
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
   this is a container
</div>
```

"This is supposed to be placed in the center... but when i positioned it as absolute, it went back to the top of the webpage. Is there anyway to bypass this."

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```css
 .container{
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 }
```